# How to efficiently modify all elements of a list of lists and add them to the existing list of lists

Tags: python, list, append

Suppose I have a list of list that looks like this:

```
myList = [[1.,1.,6.],[2.,4.,4.],[3.,3.,3.]]
```

Now I want to apply a certain function to each list in `myList` which - for the sake of simplicity - looks like this (it just divides each element of the list by the sum of this list).

```
def changeVal(l):
    return map(lambda x: x/sum(l),l)
```

Applying it to `myList` gives me:

```
modList = map(lambda x: changeVal(x), myList)
[[0.125, 0.125, 0.75],
[0.2, 0.4, 0.4],
[0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]]
```

But what I actually want is to add all elements of `modList` to `myList`. I could do this in a for-loop:

```
for sl in modList:
    myList.append(sl)
```

which gives me the desired output:

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 6.0],
 [2.0, 4.0, 4.0],
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0],
 [0.125, 0.125, 0.75],
 [0.2, 0.4, 0.4],
 [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]]
```

However, I want to do this without using a for-loop since `append` is slow. I tried:

```
myList.append(*modList)
myList.extend(*modList)
```

which both give me an `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: extend() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

Here is the code again and the desired output:

```
myList = [[1.,1.,6.],[2.,4.,4.],[3.,3.,3.]]
def changeVal(l):
    return map(lambda x: x/sum(l),l)
modList = map(lambda x: changeVal(x), myList)
```

How to add the elements of `modList` to `myList` in order to get the following output?

```
[[1.0, 1.0, 6.0],
 [2.0, 4.0, 4.0],
 [3.0, 3.0, 3.0],
 [0.125, 0.125, 0.75],
 [0.2, 0.4, 0.4],
 [0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333, 0.3333333333333333]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct function to use here would be `extend()` , but extend accepts the list you want to extend with, not the elements of that list. Try something like -

```
myList.extend(modList)
```

Example -

```
>>> l = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> l1 = [[5,6],[7,8]]
>>> l.extend(l1)
>>>
>>> l
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Though if `modList` is not used anywhere else, you can avoid creation of the intermediate list altogether, By doing -

```
myList.extend(map(lambda x: changeVal(x), myList))
```

Timeit results for both method -

```
In [42]: def func1():
   ....:     l = [[1,2],[3,4]]
   ....:     l1 = [[5,6],[7,8]]
   ....:     for i in l1:
   ....:         l.append(i)
   ....:     return l
   ....:

In [43]: def func2():
   ....:     l = [[1,2],[3,4]]
   ....:     l1 = [[5,6],[7,8]]
   ....:     l.extend(l1)
   ....:     return l
   ....:

In [44]:

In [44]: %timeit func1()
The slowest run took 8.35 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1 µs per loop

In [45]: %timeit func2()
The slowest run took 9.11 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 794 ns per loop

In [47]: %timeit func1()
The slowest run took 7.74 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 983 ns per loop

In [46]: %timeit func2()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 799 ns per loop
```

So using `.extend()` is a little bit faster than `for` loop and `.append()` .

Comment: Ok, so just the '*'; should have tried it ;) Thanks for the time comparison! I upvote it now and accept later if nothing better shows up.